# linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hey everyone, I'm having trouble with this problem. I set up two equations to be: $1+k = 0$ and $k + 2k+48$ and I got that k = -24 and or -1. But the answers don't work so my logic is clearly flawed. I think I'm going about this equation the wrong way. Any hints on how I should attack it?

Comment: k+2k+48=3k+48, but it's not an equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way to do it is to observe that the vectors are linearly independent if $$\det\pmatrix{1 &k \\k & 2k+48}\neq 0$$ which gives you the equation $$2k+48-k^2\neq0 \iff -k^2+2k+48 \neq 0$$ or equivalently $$(k+6)(k-8)\neq0$$ which gives you that $a=-6, b=8$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to see when the system in the unknowns $\alpha$ and $\beta$
$$
\alpha(1,k)+\beta(k,2k+48)=0
$$
has a nonzero solution. The explicit system is
\begin{cases}
\alpha+k\beta=0\\
k\alpha+(2k+48)\beta=0
\end{cases}
and a simple elimination on its matrix will give the answer:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & k \\
k & 2k+48
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & k \\
0 & 2k+48-k^2
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad R_2\gets R_2-kR_1
$$
So the condition for the system to have a nonzero solution is
$$
k^2-2k+48=0
$$